# JQuery price selector slider not working properly (solved)

Tags: php, jquery

The following codes are used for a price selector function in my website.

index.php

```
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_minimum_price" value="1000" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_maximum_price" value="95000" />
    <p id="price_show">1000 - 95000</p>
    <div id="price_range"></div>

...some other codes....
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
        var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
        var brand = get_filter('brand');
        var ram = get_filter('ram');
        var storage = get_filter('storage');
        var bcamera = get_filter('bcamera');
        var core = get_filter('core');
        var battery = get_filter('battery');
        var page = get_filter('page');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, minimum_price:minimum_price, maximum_price:maximum_price, brand:brand, ram:ram, storage:storage, bcamera:bcamera, core:core, battery:battery, page:page},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:1000,
        max:95000,
        values:[1000, 95000],
        step:500,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Every other filter functions are working properly.
If I set the price filter from 5000-95000, all products are supposed to show.
But the products with price showing above 10000 are not showing in the result.
If I move the filter above 10000, it starts to work.
What could be wrong?.
You can visit the webpage and try the price slier to get an idea.

fetch_data.php

```
 $queryy = "
            SELECT * FROM filterr WHERE product_status = '1' 
        ";
        if(isset($_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_price"]))
        {
            $queryy .= "
             AND product_price BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_price"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_price"]."'
            ";
        }
```

Comment: Double check that you have correct numbers. Maybe it's 100,000 instead of 10,000? Or maybe your `product_price` is in cents?

Comment: @Justinas, that might not be the problem, because database and filter values are same. cents are not used anywhere.

Comment: @Justinas, you were right , but in a different way. The database format was different from what I need.decimal(8,2)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by saving the price details in a separate column and changing the code accordingly.
Product_price column format was decimal(8,2) and price format was without the ",2".